# Cannot Print iFrame in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, printing

I'm having issues using the latest Chrome browser (As of today Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)). I use an iframe on the website to retain position when using infinite scroll. The clicked page is an iframe that sits on top of the previous page and set up so that when you hit the back button or click on return to previous page it goes back to retaining the page position from where you scrolled.

When in Print Preview view in Chrome, the previous page sits below the iframe and it has a weird stack/overlay rendering look to it where you can see through the current page (iframe) that sits on top of the previous page. Also the current page (the iframe) is cutoff after the first page. I've tried every trick on the Stack Overflow page.

I would appreciate any help. Basically I'm trying to print the iframe page in print/print preview in the latest Chrome browser. It works fine on Safari and other browsers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**on Iframe :**

```
function printMe() {
  window.print()
}
```

**parent:**

```
document.frame1.printMe()
```

Comment: Thank you. What if you were to do command+p/control+p to print?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    var ctrlDown = false,
        ctrlKey = 17,
        cmdKey = 91,
        pKey = 112;


    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == pKey ) || cmdKey && e.keyCode == pKey ) {
         // call your function
            
         return false;

        }
    });

});
`

Comment: Thank you. So that function goes inside the actual iframe and the `document.frame1.printMe();` goes into the parent div correct? I'm not sure where the `frame1` is set?